# npm ERR! No versions available for telegraf-keyboard

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install the telegram-keyboard with "npm i telegraf-keyboard" command. I used it a few months ago but now it's not working. It shows this error:
`npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS`
`npm ERR! No versions available for telegraf-keyboard`

Can anyone try and say when you run this command do you get the same error or is it from my side only?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing, feels like the repo was deleted somehow

Answer (score 0):

You mean telegram-keyboard don't you? `npm i telegram-keyboard` works fine, and [can be used in Telegraf](https://github.com/RealPeha/telegram-keyboard#example-of-use-in-telegraf).